# How to define an associative array in Nelmio API DOC vs 3?

Tags: symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

I am using Symfomy 3.4 with Nelmio API DOC vs 3.

I have a GET API with a multiplier parameter of the format:
multiplier[14]=2&multiplier[15]=1. I want to be able to make the request from /api-doc panel with the keys of the array, not only the values. At this moment, I can add only values.

The way I am defining the relationship at this moment is:

```
     * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="multiplier",
 *     in="query",
 *     type="array",
 *     description="multiply the received reward",
 *     @SWG\Items(
 *         type="integer",
 *     ),
 *     required=false
 * )
```

I tried several things, like

```
     *     @SWG\Property(
 *          type="string"
 *     ),
```

but it seems not to work.

How can I make the key appear in the panel so I can complete it there, without using something external, such as Postman?

Comment: This is not possible - you are using OpenAPI 2.0 which does not support objects in the query string. I think this is not possible in OpenAPI 3.0 (`@OA\...`) either because it supports associative arrays with string keys only, that is `?multiplier[string_key]=value` but not `?multiplier[14]=value`.

Comment: thank you. great to know I don't have to look any further.